# WCAT 6.3 Connection Issue

Tags: iis, wcat

I am encountering an issue when running wcat from a local host to a remote iis server. During the warmup period all 10 connections are made successfully, but during the duration period no connections are made. Please see results below.

Any assistance with this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Beginning collecting statistics.

---

WARMUP   300/300 secs                            0 hours, 5 minutes, 0 seconds

---

```
Connections =                       10 (0/sec)
Disconnects =                        0 (0/sec)
Socket Sends =                  311737 (1039/sec)
Socket Receives =              1089259 (3630/sec)
Full Handshakes =                   10 (0/sec)
Reconnect Handshakes =               0 (0/sec)
Bytes Sent =                         0 (0/sec)
Bytes Received =                     0 (0/sec)
Bytes Sent (SSL) =           302611842 (1008706/sec)
Bytes Received (SSL) =     13456282547 (44854275/sec)
Time To First Byte =                 0 (Minimum)
Time To First Byte =               302 (Maximum)
Time To First Byte =                 6 (Average)
Time To Last Byte =                  0 (Minimum)
Time To Last Byte =                626 (Maximum)
Time To Last Byte =                  6 (Average)
Transactions =                   25972 (86/sec)
Normal Requests =                    0 (0/sec)
Secure Requests =              311717 (1039/sec)
Normal Responses =                   0 (0/sec)
Secure Responses =              311717 (1039/sec)
Status 200 =                    311717 (1039/sec)
Total Errors =                       0 (0/sec)
Connect Errors =                     0 (0/sec)
Send Errors =                        0 (0/sec)
Receive Errors =                     0 (0/sec)
Parsing Errors =                     0 (0/sec)
Unexpected Status =                  0 (0/sec)
```

Finished collecting statistics.

---

DURATION 300/300 secs                           0 hours, 10 minutes, 0 seconds ******************************************************************************
    Connections =                  0 (0/sec)
    Disconnects =                  0 (0/sec)
    Socket Sends =            351671 (1172/sec)
    Socket Receives =        1228662 (4095/sec)
    Full Handshakes =              0 (                       0/sec)
    Reconnect Handshakes =                        0 (                       0/sec)
    Bytes Sent =                        0 (                       0/sec)
    Bytes Received =                        0 (                       0/sec)
    Bytes Sent (SSL) =                341408171 (                 1138027/sec)
    Bytes Received (SSL) =              15181738222 (                50605794/sec)
    Time To First Byte =                        0 (                     Minimum)
    Time To First Byte =                      394 (                     Maximum)
    Time To First Byte =                        7 (                     Average)
    Time To Last Byte =                        0 (                      Minimum)
    Time To Last Byte =                      620 (                     Maximum)
    Time To Last Byte =                        7 (                     Average)
    Transactions =                    29304 (                      97/sec)
    Normal Requests =                        0 (                       0/sec)
    Secure Requests =                   351671 (                    1172/sec)
    Normal Responses =                        0 (                       0/sec)
    Secure Responses =                   351671 (                    1172/sec)
    Status 200 =                   351671 (                    1172/sec)
    Total Errors =                        0 (                       0/sec)
    Connect Errors =                        0 (                       0/sec)
    Send Errors =                        0 (                       0/sec)
    Receive Errors =                        0 (                       0/sec)
    Parsing Errors =                        0 (                       0/sec)
    Unexpected Status =                        0 (                       0/sec)